# Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code, this error:

*Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type*

my code:

```py
cur.execute("UPDATE  weather SET number=(?) where city=(?)" ,(UPDATE_NUMBER,CITY))
```

type(UPDATE_NUMBER): tuple

type(CITY):tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of the values argument to `cursor.execute` are tuples, but they should be scalar values such as `int`s or `str`s.

Your code may look like

```
cur.execute("UPDATE weather SET number=(?) where city=(?)", ((1,), ('Tokyo',)))
```

but it should be

```
cur.execute("UPDATE weather SET number=(?) where city=(?)", (1, 'Tokyo'))
```